# Interactive TCL shell shows no output in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, tcl, vivado

I am running Vivado in TCL mode under cygwin and noticed that I do not get any output in return to some commands I enter.
The commands which do not return anything seem to be non-builtins or commands which require OS interaction, as far as I can tell.
Consider the following example:

```
$ vivado -mode tcl
puts HelloTcl

****** Vivado v2015.4.2 (64-bit)
  **** SW Build 1494164 on Fri Feb 26 04:18:56 MST 2016
  **** IP Build 1491208 on Wed Feb 24 03:25:39 MST 2016
    ** Copyright 1986-2015 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

HelloTcl
puts 2
2
expr 1 + 2
puts 5
5
help synth_design
read_vhdl
ERROR: [Common 17-163] Missing value for option 'files', please type 'read_vhdl -help' for usage info.

package require Tcl
pwd
exit
exit
INFO: [Common 17-206] Exiting Vivado at Fri Jul 14 13:44:28 2016...
```

The commands which did not return the expected output are `expr 1 + 2`, `help synth_design` and `pwd` (and possibly `package require Tcl`).
The situation is the same with the "normal" tclsh.
Can anyone help me understand what the reason of this behavior is?

My OS is Win7 Pro 64bit. Everything works fine with cmd or Powershell. The behavior is also as expected when running Vivado in a terminal under Linux.

Comment: In case of expr, there was no `puts` i.e. `puts [expr 1 + 2]`

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that vivado is only writing values out when you explicitly ask for it, unlike with a standard interactive tclsh which *also* writes out the result of each command (provided it isn't the empty string). You need to write an explicit `puts […]`.

```
puts [expr 1 + 2]
puts [pwd]
```

As long as you know about it, I guess it's not too big a deal. Just a bit annoying.

Comment: As for _why_, because they use their own read-evaluate-loop and don't include a print step.

Comment: The odd thing is that the behavior Vivado is as expected of an interactive tclsh when I run it in cmd/powershell or in a terminal in my Fedora VM. The "unexpected behavior" is only seen with cygwin. (I updated my question to add this information.)